# Add bottom border for UISearchBar textField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, border, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` added to a `navigationItem`'s titleView.
I would like to add a bottom border to the `UISearchBar`'s textField.

When try to add a layer, nothing appears.

```
extension UITextField {

func underlined() {

         let border = CALayer()
         let width = CGFloat(3.0)
         border.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: width)
         border.borderWidth = width
         self.layer.addSublayer(border)
         self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

}

I tried this code to get the content of the textField, but without luck.

```
let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField

textFieldInsideSearchBar?.borderStyle = .none
textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.white
textFieldInsideSearchBar?.underlined()
```

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Try this key "_searchField"

Answer (score 2):

Thats because in viewDidLoad method, frames not configured properly yet, try this:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField
    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.borderStyle = .none
    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.white
    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.underlined()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code to read searchbar's textfield and setUnderline in viewDidAppear(:) method instead of viewDidLoad(:).

The problem is you are setting the textField sublayer before its getting its frame. Try printing the frame of the textfield and you will find (0,0,0,0) which leads to the y position of the sublayer to zero. So, set it after the view appears thus it will have its bounds and y position to the desired.